# JDBC Inbound Adapter retrieving only one record rather than all

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using following jdbc inbound adapter that retrieves the message. There is another activator that monitors the channel and calls a method. However the issue is, the service activator is getting only one "Event" and not all. But, the query is supposed to "select *"

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInboundAdapter"
                                 channel="queueChannel" data-source="datasource"
                                 auto-startup="true"
                                 query="SELECT * FROM Event" row-mapper="eventResultMapper"
                                 update-per-row="false">

    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="queueChannel" ref="eventActivator" method="doSomething">
</int:service-activator>
```

I have also tried to add max-rows="0" in the adapter, but that didn't help.

Comment: Maybe your `eventResultMapper` returns just only a first item in the cursom? Can you turn on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` category to see what and how `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` producing

Comment: I debugged it further. The value of canProcessMessageList is false while creating ServiceActivatingHandler. Thus, service activator receives only one event rather than list. The activator looks as follows:                                        public void doSomething(Event event){
        System.out.println("Processing event: " + event.getName());
    }  I can see that there are 4 messages on queueChannel. How can I set this to true so that activator receives all 4 messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further debugging, it turned out that the value of canProcessMessageList is false while creating ServiceActivatingHandler. Thus, service activator receives only one event rather than list.

This is how my activator looked like:

```
public void doSomething(Event event)
{
  System.out.println("Processing event: " + event.getName());
}
```

Updated activator with following signature and it worked:

```
public void doSomething(Collection<Event> events){
    System.out.println("Processing event: " + events.size());
    for (Event event: events){
        System.out.print("***** " + event.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you figured out it yourself! you now can accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks Artem. SO says I cannot accept it for 2 days.

Comment: That's fine. Just keep int in mind and it is going to be helpful for other people here on SO.